# Drop in dataTransfer not working in cypress( drag is fine)

Tags: cypress, drag, drop

I have a scenario where I need to drag an item from one listbox to another. When I tried with dataTransfer, I could see the item is removed from the listbox1 but it is not dropping it in listbox2. I could also see it has identified the place to drop the item too. but it is not able to drop it over there. Any suggestions? I am using cypress version 4.1.2. I tried the following steps:

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

```
      cy.get('#draggable:nth-child(1)').trigger("dragstart", {dataTransfer});(This works)
      cy.get('#droppable:nth-child(1)').trigger("dragover"); (This works)
      cy.get('#droppable:nth-child(1)').trigger("drop", {dataTransfer});(This doesn't work!)
```

Comment: Please not that the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `:` in the last selector, is that a typo or does it resolve your problem?

```
  cy.get('#draggable:nth-child(1)').trigger("dragstart", {dataTransfer});
  cy.get('#droppable:nth-child(1)').trigger("dragover"); 
  cy.get('#droppable:nth-child(1)').trigger("drop", {dataTransfer});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected it now. But that is not the real issue.